# How to implement an interpolatable interface in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, interface

I am trying to implement software renderer, which interpolation happens after vertex shading

The following is its declaration

```cpp
template <class T>
class Interpolatable
{
    // The function calculates an interpolated value
    // along the fraction t between 0.0 and 1.0. 
    // When t = 1.0, endValue is returned.
    virtual T interpolate(const T &endValue, float t)=0;
};

struct Vertex: public Interpolatable<?????????>
{
    float x, y, z;

    Vertex()=default;
    Vertex(float, float, float);

    virtual Vertex &interpolate(const Vertex &endValue, float t) const;
};
```

Is it possible to make Vertex's interpolate method return instance of Vertex?
The compiler keeps giving me errors

Comment: struct Vertex: public Interpolatable<Vertex> Do you want to use CRTP?

Comment: `struct Vertex: interpolatable<Vertex>` should work. Note you need to return `Vertex`, **not** `Vertex&`

Comment: You seem to miss a `T const& beginValue` to return for the case `t==0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a class' name as a template argument safely, but any errors you're getting are due to a function signature mismatch.

```
struct Vertex: public Interpolatable<Vertex>

virtual T interpolate(const T &endValue, float t)=0;
virtual Vertex &interpolate(const Vertex &endValue, float t) const;
//             ^reference                                      ^declared const
```

It seems that your signatures should be:

```
virtual T interpolate(const T &endValue, float t) const =0;
virtual Vertex interpolate(const Vertex &endValue, float t) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you fix the three errors:

- `?????????` should be `Vertex`
- `interpolate` should return `Vertex` by value
- `interpolate` should not be `const` (or should be `const` in the base class)

Comment: Is it possible to declare pure virtual and const method at the same time?

Comment: Yes, `void foo() const =0;`

Comment: Yes, but change the order of =0 and const is illegal

Comment: @TimHsu: Yes, you need to put them in the right order, as TartanLlama did.